# My app crashes giving error Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

This code creates a reference in Firebase storage and saving the image in storage.Then saving the text and image URL of the in database.
It works fine on my one phone(API 28) but crashes on other(API 25).

I checked previous queries to similar question but were not specific.

```
private void uploadImage(final Uri imageFile) {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading File");
        progressDialog.setProgress(0);
        progressDialog.show();

        storageReference.child("Users").child(Objects.requireNonNull(auth.getCurrentUser()).getUid()).child(f_name.getText().toString()+" "+ l_name.getText().toString()).putFile(imageFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                String du = Objects.requireNonNull(taskSnapshot.getUploadSessionUri()).toString();
                Log.i("session url ", du);
                String du1 = du.substring(0, du.indexOf("&uploadType"));
                String du3 = "&alt=media";
                downloadUrl = du1 + du3;
                Log.i("download url url ", downloadUrl);

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(Info.this, "Inside failure listener failed to store file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                int currentProgress = (int) (100 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                progressDialog.setProgress(currentProgress);

            }
        });
databaseReference.child("Users").child(Objects.requireNonNull(auth.getCurrentUser()).getUid()).child("Name").setValue(f_name.getText().toString()+" "+ l_name.getText().toString());
        databaseReference.child("Users").child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Profile Image").setValue(downloadUrl);
```

Error:

```
Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
could not obtain extracted text (class com.touchtype.keyboard.c.aj)
```

Comment: Are you getting  "downloadUrl" in Log

Comment: No downloadurl is not visible in log

Comment: so i tried removing 
that downloadurl code it worked well 
but now i cannot generate url for the image..
it works fine in one phone but not in mine.
So is this a wrong way to generate url??